# Felix doesn't like javax.script

Tags: java, osgi, javax.script, apache-felix

I'm writing an OSGI bundle using the javax.script package and am having some issues getting Felix to load the package correctly. When attempting to start the bundle, I'm getting:

Failed bundle start for org.plugin.script.plugin-scripter [2]: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle 2: package; (package=javax.script)

which I think happens when we try to reference a package which isn't correctly loaded into the bundle. I'm fairly certain this is down to the fact that javax.script is only bundled into the JDK starting 1.6 and for some reason Maven is building using something else. So far I've:

a. Set the necessary import in my Maven POM for Felix by:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Export-Package>org.plugin.script</Export-Package>
            <Private-Package>org.plugin.script.*</Private-Package>
            <Bundle-Activator>org.plugin.script.ScripterPlugin</Bundle-Activator>
            <Import-Package>!*,javax.script,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",javax.naming,javax.naming.spi</Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>!org.apache.felix*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            <Embed-Directory>dependency</Embed-Directory>
            <Embed-StripGroup>true</Embed-StripGroup>
            <_failok>true</_failok>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

b. Set the Maven compiler to 1.6 since that's the earliest we get javax.script

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

c. Not even sure if this makes a difference but I set Felix's framework properties (in their config.properties) to 1.6.0 and included the javax.script export. TBH I'm not sure about this one but figured I'd take a shot.

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=org.osgi.framework; version=1.3.0, \
    [lots of stuff in between]
    javax.script; \
    version="1.6.0"
```

Still nadda tho. What else did I miss ?

Comment: Just a random hint - it looks like the error is happening when you attempt to load the bundle, so have you checked that your *execution* platform is Java 1.6?

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the hint but that was the first suspicion. I've actually removed all versions except for 1.6 so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Ah new developments. The manifest tells me that the javax.script package was in Export-Package (under the uses:) and Import-Package but *also* in the Ignore-Package which is weird because I've never set it as such.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Import-Package>!*,javax.script,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",javax.naming,javax.naming.spi</Import-Package>
```

Typically you want to let bnd import everything a bundle needs. Here you are telling it to not import anything (i.e., "!*"). Order is important here. Since * matches anything, your bundle won't import anything. Try removing the Import-Package completely (which will default importing everything) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the holler. !* was actually done so I could keep the size of the bundle down. Figured it'd be better for me to explicitly state individual imports instead of having bnd grab everything and make the jar obese. In any case I still ran into the unresolved constraint exception. The manifest (after removing the Import-Package) looks fine tbh:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Export-Package: org.plugin.script;uses:="javax.script, etc etc"
Import-Package: javax.script, etc etc

Starting to make less sense overall :P

Comment: Some interesting misconceptions here. The Import-Package statement does not do anything to the size of your bundle, that is controlled by the Private-Package and Export-Package statements. Bnd does not "grab everything"... it grabs exactly what you have used in your Java code and nothing more. So by overriding it with !* you are actually saying "do not import these packages EVEN THOUGH my code uses them".

Comment: As to the unresolved constraint error... this simply means that there is no other bundle exporting the package that your bundle needs. If you are running on Java 6 then the "system bundle" *should* export this package because it is part of the standard libs on Java 6. If you are running on Java 5 or earlier then you need a separate bundle that exports that package.

Comment: @Neil Cheers for the correction mate. Huge misconception there and I can confirm that your observations are right on the money. Is there any Felix configuration I need to set so that it runs explicitly on Java 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that *some* bundle is exporting that package. I think you can use commands like "headers" for this depending on your environment (Felix, Equinox, etc). If you are in fact exporting it from *somewhere* then I would try narrowing it down to a specific version.

Hope this helps.